# How to use Clang tidy in CMake

Tags: cmake, clang-tidy

I would like to use CMake and [clang-tidy](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/) in my project. However, I see that build times are quite a bit higher when I use this in all the main CMake file:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY
  clang-tidy-11;
  -format-style='file';
  -header-filter=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR};
)
```

It is working well, but I don't want to have this build-time penalty every time I build the project during development. Therefore I thought I would make a separate target that builds all, but uses clang-tidy. And when I do a regular debug or release build it does not do any checking. However, I don't know how to do this in CMake. Do I make a custom target with a command "cmake --build" with a target_set_property of CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY?

This feels rather clunky, so are there other ways to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> however I see that build times are quite a bit higher when I use this in all the main cmake file:

You're going to have to pay for the cost of running `clang-tidy` sometime or another. It's essentially running the first few phases of a compiler to analyze your code and look for errors.

Setting `CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY` runs `clang-tidy` in line with your build, as you have observed.

> This feels rather clunky, so my question is, are there other ways to do this?

Yes. When using the Ninja or Makefile generators, you may set `-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON` at the command line. That will create a file called `compile_commands.json` in your build folder that the standalone `clang-tidy` can read.

In sum, at the command line, you would manually run:

```
$ cmake -G Ninja -S . -B build -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON
$ clang-tidy-11 -format-style=file -header-filter=. -p build
```

The `-p` flag tells `clang-tidy` in which directory to find your `compile_commands.json`.

Comment: Note that simply copying the commands from this answer won't work, clang-tidy still needs a list of source files to target, simply supplying the `-p` path to `compile_commands.json` is not sufficient, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75330301/using-clang-tidy-with-compile-commands-json-to-parse-multiple-files

Comment: you can use 'run-clang-tidy.py' from the llvm codebase: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/clang-tools-extra/clang-tidy/tool/run-clang-tidy.py