# Using clang-tidy with compile-commands.json to parse multiple files

Tags: clang-tidy

I am having trouble getting clang-tidy to read my compilation-database.
If I try:

```
clang-tidy --config-file ./.clang-tidy -checks=* -p ./target
```

or

```
clang-tidy --config-file ./.clang-tidy -checks=* -p ./target/compile-commands.json
```

I get

```
Error: no input files specified.
USAGE: clang-tidy [options] <source0> [... <sourceN>]
...
```

But according to the --help -p is the way to specify the path to it.
It only seems to work if I specify individual files as in:

```
clang-tidy --config-file ./.clang-tidy -checks=* path/to/file.cpp
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say, "according to the --help -p is the way to specify the path to it", I think you're referring to this passage from the [Clang-Tidy](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/) page:

```
-p <build-path> is used to read a compile command database.

        For example, it can be a CMake build directory in which a file named
        compile_commands.json exists (use -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON
        CMake option to get this output). When no build path is specified,
        a search for compile_commands.json will be attempted through all
        parent paths of the first input file . See:
        https://clang.llvm.org/docs/HowToSetupToolingForLLVM.html for an
        example of setting up Clang Tooling on a source tree.
```

As it says, `-p` helps `clang-tidy` find the [compilation database](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html), which tells `clang-tidy` how to compile the listed source files, but it does not actually specify what files to analyze.  (In general, the database can say how to compile many things, but you might only want to analyze a subset.)

To specify what to analyze, you have to list all of the file names on the command line after the options.  There is, perhaps unfortunately, no way to ask `clang-tidy` to analyze everything in the compilation database.

Comment: "There is, perhaps unfortunately, no way to ask clang-tidy to analyze everything in the compilation database." was the information I was looking for.

Comment: I basically ended up with:

 SOURCE=$(find src -name \*.cpp)
 clang-tidy -p ./target/compile-commands.json ${SOURCE}

Answer (score 2):

```
USAGE: clang-tidy [options] <source0> [... <sourceN>]
```

You specified the options, you did not give `<source0>`.

What is the advantage of using `--config-file ./.clang-tidy -checks=* -p`? You set checks in `.clang-tidy` and immediately reset them with `-checks=* -p`.

`.clang-tidy` is a deafault config file, `--config-file ./.clang-tidy` can be omitted.

```
clang-tidy  -checks=* -p ./target  path/to/file.cpp
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                   options              source0
```